# Unable to create vagrant file (homestead.yaml) on windows

Tags: laravel, cygwin, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm gonna to use vagrant on my windows desktop to develop Laravel project.
 I have followed all the steps to do that. But it has been failed to create homestead.yaml using bash init.sh command.

Below is the error :

`Fakhreddin@Lenovo-PC3 /cygdrive/d/laravel-vagrant/homestead
$ bash init.sh
cp: unwritable ‘/home/Fakhreddin/.homestead/Homestead.yaml’ (mode 0500, r-x------); try anyway?`

I'm using Cygwin for simulating Unix terminal in the Windows.

Comment: So, what happens when you "try anyway", as the console suggests? Also, did you try running the command with `sudo`? Meaning `sudo bash init.sh` ? Also, did you try to delete Homestead.yaml and run `init` again? This looks like permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @lesssugar. `Sudo`  command doesn't exist in the Cygwin . 
And also for your suggestion _deleting homestead and trying again_ : I have said the process failed to create homestead . So there is no homestead.yaml exist . 
yes this looks like permission issue in the windows and i don't know how to solve that.

Comment: OK, I see. Never used Cygwin in my life. but what I would try is to run it as Administrator and re-try. Otherwise, you may want to consider changing console client. For example, if you install Git, you should be able to use Unix commands via standard Windows console. I would seriously point the fault at Cygwin, or its settings. I am a member of a team in which all of us run Homestead on Windows 7, with no problems at all. The difference is, we use native Windows command line. Good luck.

Comment: Oh man . Thanks . I have used CMD as you mentioned and it's work !!!!
I have never thought that cygwin failed to do but CMD can be able . 
You can post it as an answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Copy of the comment I wrote above)*

Never used Cygwin in my life, but what I would try is to **run it as Administrator** and re-try.

Otherwise, you may want to consider **changing console client**. For example, if you install Git, you should be able to use Unix commands via standard Windows console.

I would seriously point the fault at Cygwin, or its settings. I am a member of a team in which all of us run Homestead on Windows 7, with no problems at all. The difference is, we use native Windows command line.